# Reset Many Drop Down Boxes To Null Value Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, drop-down-menu, shapes

I have a sheet that has a few hundred drop down boxes. I want a button that resets them all to the null or top value when clicked. I can get it to work for individual drop downs but I can't get the syntax right to loop through a group of them. I've tried everything I can think of to append "i" onto "Drop Down" but can't get it to work.

This works fine, I don't want to write this a few hundred times:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 260").ControlFormat.Value = 1
```

How do I get this to work:

```
For i = 1 To 260
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down & i").ControlFormat.Value = 1
Next i
```

I've tried `("Drop Down" & " " & "i")`, `("Drop Down" & " " & i)`, and everything else I could think of. I've exhausted Google and can't figure it out.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the name doesn't match with your combobox because ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down " & i).ControlFormat.Value = 1 works for me

Comment: Are they ActiveX or Form Controls?

Comment: Thank you both. When I click on them they are all "Drop Down" followed by a number. They are form controls not activex. By the way the error I get is "The item with the specified name wasn't found."

Comment: I just tried again on a new blank sheet. This doesn't work for me: Sub click()
Dim i As Integer

`For i = 1 To 5
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down " & i).ControlFormat.Value = 1
Next i

End Sub`

Comment: Any other ideas or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I know why it's not working, I don't have a sequential number of drop down boxes, somewhere there is a break so say when i = 27 and Drop Down 27 doesn't exist there is an error. What I want to do is write an if statement ahead of this that checks for the existence of "Drop Down i" prior to clearing it. I tried "If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down " & 1) = True Then" but that's not valid.

Comment: The "VBA 2" solution here works: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4853-excel-vba-clear-contents-of-combobox.html

Comment: The link I posted clears the list box contents, not what I wanted. It took me a while to find, but all that is needed is this: ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Value = 0